# Image resize, resample, maintain ASPECT RATIO and ORIENTATION, thumbnail generation using php

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3, imagemagick

I am building a website using

- php 5.3,
- Twitter Bootstrap
- MySQL,

Which includes a few features where registered users can create their own profile, upload avatar, cover photo, update status, share photos etc.

Since I am a newbie to all the 3 technologies mentioned above I rely completely on the internet to get my job done. Right now I am having trouble in resizing, re-sampling and maintaining aspect ratios and orientation of the uploaded images using `GD` library.
My expectations are:

1. Reduce the file size of images while maintaining the quality and aspect ratio.
2. Maintain orientation [many images are rotated horizontally, something to do with exif I guess].
3. Generate 4 different sized thumbnails [30x30, 40x40, 55x55 and a large one for cover pic].

   I tried many options, but haven't found a single solution which does all of this. I came across `ImageMagick` library which looks promising, but not sure whether it serves my purpose. Please help me with code snippets or examples related to my requirements.

P.S. If in case my question was not clear, I am trying to achieve image manipulations like Facebook and Twitter do.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Raheel Khan. Link redirects to a blank page......

Comment: Please follow this link i'm sorry for last link it was for cloning.
https://gist.github.com/raheelkhan/1c41c15d6d376d9ee869

Comment: It is not so advanced but can do a basic stuff when providing a desire with as i mentioned in the example.

Answer (score 0):

My answer will not solve your problem,but will help you to know something else.You can minifiy your image size (up to 80%) and keep you images with that size.Here is a tool which you can check out.http://www.w3docs.com/tools/minimage/

Comment: But that's the whole point of my question. I am finding different bits and pieces of code which does only one of many things I need to achieve. I am last oking for a single, or at least a bunch of things I can combine to achieve my goal. Thank you